# Form Processing

Tags: php, cakephp

i am working on a application for making exams.

I have 3 tables **(exams/questions/options)**

```
exams table : id,name
questions table : id,name,exam_id
options tables : id,name,question_id
```

**exams hasMany questions hasMany options.**

Now, i set my questions with the related options and then add it to the exam. So far so good.

But, when i want to do the exam i am stuck in the validation process.

e.g i have a `do_exam.ctp` with the following code:

```
<?php echo $form->create(null, array('action' => 'validate_answer')); ?>
<h3>Do Exam</h3>
<?php if(!$questions) {?>
<h4>No Questions Found!</h4>
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach($questions as $question):?>
<h4>Question</h4>
<?php echo $question['Question']['qst']; ?>
    <h4>Make an Option</h4>
     <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($question['Option'] as $option):
        $class = null;
        if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
            $class = ' class="altrow"';
        }
    ?>
    <tr<?php echo $class;?>>

        <td><?php echo $option['Type'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $option['opt'];?></td>

    <br />            
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <br />
    <?php $options = array('A' => 'A', 'B' => 'B','C' => 'C', 'D' => 'D');
        echo $form->select('answer', $options);
        echo $form->hidden('ca', array('value' => $question['Question']['Correct_Answer'] ));
    ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo $form->end('Finish!'); ?> `
```

and at the exams controller i want to validate if it is the correct answer. I don't want to store it anywhere just check if the answer is correct or not.

any help?

Comment: how do you intend validating the answer when you do not store the correct answer in any of tables? Question is not very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to store the correct answer if you don't want the user to have the option to keep track of his progress.

I'm sure you have somewhere in your question or in your option some column like `correct_answer`. Don't put it as a hidden field in your form. Every little kid who can use the sourcecode-view could see the correct answer.

At first you have to write your input like this in your foreach:

```
foreach ($questions as $i => $question) {
    echo $this->Form->input('Exam.'.$i.'.question_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $question['Question']['id']));
    echo $this->Form->input('Exam.'.$i.'.answer');
}
echo $this->Form->end('Finish!');
```

This is important so that you have all questions in one array.

What you do now in your function could look something like this:

```
function validate_answer() {
    if (isset($this->data)) {
        foreach ($this->data['Exam'] as $exam) {
            $this->Exam->Question->id = $exam['question_id'];
            $correct_answer = $this->Exam->Question->field('correct_answer');
            $user_answer = $exam['answer'];
            if ($correct_answer == $user_answer) {
                //do something with it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This just for the basics. Hope this helps to get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you Tim! I will try your code and i will tell you about the results..its clear i understand your point.

Comment: Your code is working just perfect. i change some code lines in my controller code and view code. Everything is ok now..i can continue with the rest of my app. Thank y very much for your help Tim.